# Linux Drastically Underclocking CPU (i5-4300U CPU)

Tags: linux, cpu, temperature, intel-core-i5, acpi

Currently working on an issue and am looking for some guidance.
Our current setup is a dual core (i5-4300U) Advantech box running Ubuntu 14.04.

I am seeing these rare occasions where the CPU cores go from ~2GHz and get immediately underclocked to 250 MHz and it stays there until I reboot the system.
Note that the `cpuinfo_min_freq` is set to 800MHz and that the power scaling governor is set to power savings.

My initial reaction was that it was temperature related but looking at the temperature, the cores are normally around the mid 30s C and were at the high 30s when this latest incident occurred.  Which does not seem like its too drastic of a jump or out of a healthy. See attached screen shots.

[image: CPU Frequency]

[image: Core Temperature]

A few questions:

- Are there other factors outside of temperature that would cause the CPU frequency to be reduced like it is?
- Does it seem odd that it would be reduced below the min setting?  What would cause this?
- Any other general insights or things I should look into on this setup?

  ```
  >>:~$ uname -a

  Linux host 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:06:37 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux


  >>:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
  processor   : 0
  vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
  cpu family  : 6
  model       : 69
  model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
  stepping    : 1
  microcode   : 0x16
  cpu MHz     : 1899.902
  cache size  : 3072 KB
  physical id : 0
  siblings    : 4
  core id     : 0
  cpu cores   : 2
  apicid      : 0
  initial apicid  : 0
  fdiv_bug    : no
  f00f_bug    : no
  coma_bug    : no
  fpu     : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level : 13
  wp      : yes
  flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
  bugs        :
  bogomips    : 4988.23
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor   : 1
  vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
  cpu family  : 6
  model       : 69
  model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
  stepping    : 1
  microcode   : 0x16
  cpu MHz     : 1901.953
  cache size  : 3072 KB
  physical id : 0
  siblings    : 4
  core id     : 1
  cpu cores   : 2
  apicid      : 2
  initial apicid  : 2
  fdiv_bug    : no
  f00f_bug    : no
  coma_bug    : no
  fpu     : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level : 13
  wp      : yes
  flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
  bugs        :
  bogomips    : 4988.23
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor   : 2
  vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
  cpu family  : 6
  model       : 69
  model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
  stepping    : 1
  microcode   : 0x16
  cpu MHz     : 1899.902
  cache size  : 3072 KB
  physical id : 0
  siblings    : 4
  core id     : 0
  cpu cores   : 2
  apicid      : 1
  initial apicid  : 1
  fdiv_bug    : no
  f00f_bug    : no
  coma_bug    : no
  fpu     : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level : 13
  wp      : yes
  flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
  bugs        :
  bogomips    : 4988.23
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor   : 3
  vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
  cpu family  : 6
  model       : 69
  model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
  stepping    : 1
  microcode   : 0x16
  cpu MHz     : 1902.246
  cache size  : 3072 KB
  physical id : 0
  siblings    : 4
  core id     : 1
  cpu cores   : 2
  apicid      : 3
  initial apicid  : 3
  fdiv_bug    : no
  f00f_bug    : no
  coma_bug    : no
  fpu     : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level : 13
  wp      : yes
  flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
  bugs        :
  bogomips    : 4988.23
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:
  ```

Comment: Does it help to set the governor to performance or kill all power/cpufreq daemons?

Comment: I'll have to try this.

Answer (score 4):

### Is that speed supported?

Is 250MHz even a supported frequency? Looking here should show what's available (250MHz would appear as 250000):

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

### Are you seeing accurate speeds?

Ignoring what the set minimum should be, if 250MHz isn't even supported then I'm guessing either the frequency monitor program you're using is having problems, or the frequency daemon (kernel?) is.

What are you using to monitor the cpu frequency? `cpufreq-info` (from cpufrequtils), or directly reading the "cpu MHz" line from `/proc/cpuinfo` or

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

or depending on your driver (in the `scaling_driver` file)

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

I'd definitely check all of them when the issue comes up.

It's also worth checking the general performance when the problem happens too. Comparing a benchmark to it's speed when the CPU is acting normally could help confirm if it's really slowing down, or just "saying" it's slow. Good benchmarks include:

- `openssl speed md5` (thanks David Schwartz)
- `cryptsetup benchmark`
- One of the benchmarks from `hardinfo` ([Ubuntu's help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/hardinfo), [GitHub](http://hardinfo.org/))

  - archlinux's wiki has a nice page on [Benchmarking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Benchmarking) in general
- Just watching `dd`'s GB/s speed on virtual "files" might be sufficient (though it varies ~0.5GB/s with each run in my tests just now):

  ```
  if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M count=10000
  10000+0 records in
  10000+0 records out
  10485760000 bytes (10 GB, 9.8 GiB) copied, 1.69302 s, 6.2 GB/s
  ```

If it appears to be a confirmed problem with all sources, I'd try  a different kernel.

Comment: It may be helpful to run a quick performance test, like `openssl speed md5`, to see if the CPU performance is in line with the reported speed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Excellent idea, `cryptsetup benchmark` might work too. I forgot to mention something similar, at the time I couldn't think of a good command to `time`, but a benchmark's likely best

Comment: Great ideas, thanks!!      I am using the information in /proc and /sys (ultimately, its a node scraper from Prometheus gathering the data).     I know for certain that the CPU is drastically being unclocked (processes running that typically run at 10-20% CPU all of the sudden slam up in usage due to the lower clock rate).     Any thoughts on how to get debugging information in terms of why the kernel is making this sudden decision?   Not seeing anything in kern.log

Comment: I'm not too sure about debugging... For a fix could try changing the governor, or unload/reload the module (cpufreq_ondemand / cpufreq_conservative, etc... or acpi_cpufreq)?  Found some basic [cpufrequtils info on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling) but it mentions the [intel_pstate driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) isn't modular, so can't be unloaded. [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) has `cpupower` help (like cpufreq but slightly different flags?)